# Integrating jdoodle ide in react not rendering

Tags: javascript, iframe, jdoodle

I'm trying to integrate [JDoodle IDE](https://docs.jdoodle.com/integrating-compiler-ide-to-your-application/ide-plugin) in React app .

I'm using Frame library

```
<Frame>
  <IDE />
</Frame>
```

IDE component

```
export function IDE(props: any) {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        data-pym-src="https://www.jdoodle.com/plugin"
        data-language="java"
        data-version-index="4"
      >
      </div>
      <script
        src="https://www.jdoodle.com/assets/jdoodle-pym.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"
      ></script>
    </>
  );
}
```

I get blank output.

I'm expecting to get this [IDE](https://www.jdoodle.com/plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little late to answer this.
But you can make use of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and pass HTML as a string in it property.

```
const IDE = () => {
  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html lang="en">
            <head>
              <title>JDoodle Plugin - Example</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              <div
                data-pym-src="https://www.jdoodle.com/plugin"
                data-language="java"
                data-version-index="4"
                interactive="true"
                data-libs="org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4"
              ></div>
              <script
                src="https://www.jdoodle.com/assets/jdoodle-pym.min.js"
                type="text/javascript"
              ></script>
            </body>
          </html>
`,
      }}
    ></div>
  );
};

export default IDE;
```